# Custom Editor Xamarin Forms for handling rich text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to create a Editor that can handle the rich text and provide similar behavior showing in image in iOS, Android and UWP device.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor maybe help

Comment: Is it work on UWP? @ColeXia

Comment: No,only for iOS and android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use syncfusion's rich text editor control.

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/rich-text-editor/overview

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should include relevant details from the link here

Comment: The syncfusion rich text editor is a commercial product.